# Why has my 'references' page title disappeared on my bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sectioning, titlesec

I cannot for the life of me find the answer to this.
Here is a full summary of my main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},left=25.4mm,top=25.4mm,right=25.4mm,bottom=25.4mm}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space, 
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}

%\bibliographystyle{}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[
            backend=bibtex,
            style=numeric,
            citestyle=numeric,
            sorting=none
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{ gensymb }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 


\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}   %for chapter headings in each tex chapter file


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapters/Introduction}
\newpage{}
\input{chapters/appendix_a}
\printbibliography %[heading = References]
\end{document}
```

My bibliography functions, and pulls in correctly, but there is no title. Usually there is a 'references' title.
Introduction.tex is:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Huge\bfseries}  
  {\thechapter \enspace Introduction}  %This title is what appears on the page
  {0pt}             
  {}


\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}   %This title is what will appear in the ToC
\fancyhead[RE]{\ref{Introduction} \nameref{Introduction}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\ref{Introduction} \nameref{Introduction}}

\section{Intro}
\begin{itemize}

    \item Outline DM astro evidence to motivate \cite{timea}
\end{itemize}
```

and refs.bib contains just:

```
@misc{timea,
    author = "Timea",
    title = {test.py},
    howpublished = {Canvas},
    note = {Accessed: 2021-12-05} ,
    year=2021,
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: your example is incomplete and so can't be tested. Extend it and use if possible biblatex-examples.bib as bib file and cite e.g. \cite{doody}, as this exist on all systems.

Comment: I add the bib file and `\cite` myself, there is the title 'Bibliography' which is different from your description.

Comment: I have edited by original post to be as complete as possible. thank you for you responses and in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the complete (though not [minimal](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) example. Not a solution but a few hints: (1) The problem appears to come from the command `\titleformat{chapter}{...`, this is from `titlesec`. I have no solution, but I'm not sure it's OK to put *actual text* in the `label` argument? Whereas you wrote `\thechapter \enspace Introduction`. (2) Remove `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}`: it  doesn't do much, bc this is `biblatex` not `bibtex`. (3) `\printbibliography[heading = References]` should be `\printbibliography[title = References]`

Comment: Thankyou @marquinho. 
Removing the \titleformat fixes the issue, so I can go forward from here and try to figure out how to get what i want.
\titleformat was for removing 'chapter' from chapter headings.

How do I make use of titleformat appropriately?

Comment: AFAICS, `\titleformat` is supposed to be a general *formatting* command, you shouldn't need to re-issue everytime you have a new chapter with a new title. That is the job of `\chapter{...}`. Try my answer (or a combination of the available answers) to have both `\titleformat` and the title "References".

Answer (score 2):

This is a cleaned up example that reproduces your problem:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[explicit]
{titlesec}

\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Huge\bfseries}  
  {\thechapter \enspace Introduction}
  {0pt}             
  {}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}   %This title is what will appear in the ToC

\section{Intro}
\cite{doody}

\printbibliography[title = References]

\end{document}
```

This gives us:
[image: bib without title]

I have commented pkg `tocbibind` out, not knowing exactly what format you want for your bibliography in the TOC. But you can take the following solution and move from there.

My suggestion:

- (1) Give up the option `explicit` of the package `titlesec`, which was suppressing the bibliography header. From the documentation: "with package option `explicit`, chapter titles must be given explicitly".
- (2) *You can actually keep* the `\titleformat` (in a slightly improved form). Mainly, you want to remove any words of *actual text* from that format, such as  "Introduction", because the command is supposed to be a general formatting directive. Providing a title for a single chapter is a job for, well, `\chapter{...}`. Good news is: without option `explicit`, now the commands `\chapter{...}` and `\titleformat` work in tandem. The expected titles such as "Introduction" pop up right where you wanted them.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\usepackage%[explicit]
{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Huge\bfseries}  
  {\thechapter\enspace} % no words of text here, and moved to the preamble
  {0pt}             
  {}

\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}   %This title is what will appear in the ToC AND the text

\section{Intro}
\cite{doody}

\printbibliography[title = References]

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image: bib with title]

You can move from here and customize the TOC (with hints from the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
```

*Notice the brackets {}*

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the content of your `Introduction.tex` with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` commands, such as:

```
\begingroup
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter \enspace Introduction}
  {0pt}
  {}

\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}
\fancyhead[RE]{\ref{Introduction} \nameref{Introduction}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\ref{Introduction} \nameref{Introduction}}

\section{Intro}
\begin{itemize}
\item Outline DM astro evidence to motivate \cite{timea}
\end{itemize}
\endgroup
```

In this way, the `\titleformat` command is only applied within that group, and the Bibliography title will appear.

And as [@eliasf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/263599/eliasf) mentioned in his answer you can use `\printbibliography[title={References}]` to show a specific title.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution i am going with.